# How to get the length of Array after Filter is applied

Tags: angular

Here is what I have in my setup, I have a AG Grid which yes to bttn above one is for refresh the grid data the other is to allow for actions like , Add New, Edit Item and Delete or some other stuff like if i am on a customer record i allow the user if a customer is selected to create a new Email Address or Phone etc. Also to make it a bit clearer, I have a component call filterGrid which is called by my components that want to use the FilterGrid. All that works fine and the way i handle that is by passing an Array of Action. What i am trying is be able to access how many items will be in my dropdown.
Currently i check the plusAction.length but it only works if there is only one item in the array. But if there is 2 but only one would apply code no longer works since plusAction.length returns total count in array not the count of items which pass the showPlusAction. I am looking for a way to get the count of items after the filter of ShowPlusAction is applied.
Below is my relevant code

```
plusActions: [
{selected: ['any'], action: 'modal', label: 'Create New FollowUp', click: (data, params) => this.handleNew(data, params)},
{selected: ['one'], action: 'modal', label: 'Edit FollowUp', click: (data, params) => this.handleEdit('page', data, params)},
{selected: ['many'], action: 'modal', label: 'Test FollowUp', click: (data, params) => this.handleTest( data, params)}]
```

then my FilterGrid i have in the template code the following Code

```
<!-- Add actions -->
<ng-container *ngIf="plusActions?.length > 0">
    <button class="align-middle"
        *ngIf="plusActions.length === 1"
        (click)="plusActions[0].click(agGridBase)">
        <igx-icon>add</igx-icon>
    </button>
    <button [igxToggleAction]="menuAddActions"
        *ngIf="plusActions.length !== 1"
            type="button"
            class="action__grid"
            [igxToggleOutlet]="outletAddActions"
            [igxDropDownItemNavigation]="menuAddActions"
            igxButton="icon"
            igxRipple>
        <igx-icon>add</igx-icon>
    </button>
<igx-drop-down #menuAddActions>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of plusActions">
        <igx-drop-down-item *ngIf="showPlusAction('modal', item)">
            <button igxButton="flat" igxRipple (click)="item.click(agGridBase)">
                {{ item.label }}
            </button>
        </igx-drop-down-item>

        <igx-drop-down-item *ngIf="showPlusAction('list-action', item)">
            <app-list-action [list]="{DocId: null, name: null, items: selectedRowIds}"></app-list-action>
        </igx-drop-down-item>

    </ng-container>
</igx-drop-down>
</ng-container>
```

And then I have the function which checks how many rows are selected and only returns the items in the dropdown which meet the criteria.

```
showPlusAction(actionName: string, plusAction) {
        console.log(this.agGridBase.selectedRowIds.length)
        if (actionName !== plusAction.action) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!plusAction.selected || !plusAction.selected.length) {
            return true;
        }
        for (const select of plusAction.selected) {
            switch (select) {
                case 'one':
                    if (this.agGridBase.selectedRowIds.length === 1) {
                        return true
                    };
                    break;
                case 'many':
                    if (this.agGridBase.selectedRowIds.length > 1) {
                        return true
                    };
                    break;
                case 'none':
                    if (this.agGridBase.selectedRowIds.length === 0) {
                        return true
                    };
                    break;
                case 'any':
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have an array called `plusActions` which you want to filter and then get the count of the remaining items after filtering.

The issue is that you are using `*ngIf` to actually do the filtering, so you are essentially just filtering them out of the DOM without changing the original array or creating a new one.

I can't tell what approach would be best given your circumstances, but I can suggest that you actually filter the `plusActions` using Typescript.

For instance, you could do:

```
filterPlusActions(actionName: string): any[] {
  return this.plusActions.filter(pa => this.showPlusAction(actionName, pa));
}
```

Obviously you will need to make some adjustments, perhaps add some more fields to assign the result of the above method. I do not suggest you call it in the template as it will be called on every change cycle which can impact performance.

---

If you are determined to do it using `*ngIf`, you should be able to do something like this:

```
@ViewChildren(IgxDropDownItemComponent) dropDownItems: QueryList<IgxDropDownItemComponent>;

// then you can use this.dropDownItems.length wherever you want (including the template)
```

The way this should work is by fetching all rendered instances of `IgxDropDownItemComponent`, so ones removed from the DOM using `*ngIf` will not be included.

Comment: The problem here is that i need to do it in dom as it is dynamic. The result depends on how many rows are selected. So if a user has no row selected items like Edit or delete will not be shown. If one is selected items like new and edit will be shown and so on. The *ngIf does that already but i need a way to get the count of items that will be shown prior to calling the ngif so i know to call the action direct or to show a drop down menu